# Request Post body is not being delivered to Express Post Handler

Tags: node.js, reactjs, request

I am trying to send the data to the backend (express) using request module, but express post handler is printing body undefined. And express is sending the 404(Bad Request). (Note :- I have activated the cross-origin resource sharing)

My React Code:-

```
const submitHandler = (e) =>{ 
e.preventDefault();    
//const url = 'http://localhost:3001/user/login';    
const response = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{    
let options = {    
 email: 'me@example.com',    
 password: 'myPassword'    
};    
const data = JSON.stringify(options);    
submit === true ? 
request.post({url:'http://localhost:3001/user/login',headers:{'content- 
type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},body:data},(error,res)=>{    
  resolve(res);
}) :    
 reject('something went wrong!')
});    

response.then((res)=>{    
console.log(res)    
}).catch((e)=>{    
 console.log(e);    
 })    
}
```

My Express code:-

```
app.post('/user/login',(req,res)=>{    
console.log(req)    
try{    
 const data = JSON.parse(req)    
 console.log('POST request initiated !',data.body);    
 console.log(data);    
 res.send('Post request got it! ',+data);    
}catch(e){    
 res.status(400).send('Bad Request !');    
 }    
})    

app.listen(port,()=>{    
 console.log('Server is running at PORT ',port)    
})
```

The Output is:-
 body: {},
  route:
   Route {
     path: '/user/login',
     stack: [ [Layer] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }

Comment: Do you have bodyParser required and initialized?

Comment: Thankyou for response Len, I didn't use the bodyParser but in his place  i used express.json() in express file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in json middleware in Express, so that you don't have to parse every request individually:

```
const express = require("express"),
      app = express();

app.use(express.json());
```

After using it you can access the post data in the request.body property.

And btw you are getting the error because you are trying to parse the whole request object which isn't in json format.